# Update Vaadin 6.7.9 to 6.7.10 and NamingEnumeration

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

I've got a strange problem when I'm updating Vaadin 6.7.9 to 6.7.10 or 6.8++.

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.getSearchReply(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreElements(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.Collections.list(Unknown Source)
                at -----------------------------.getGroups(---.java:804)
```

**getGroups()**

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = this.searchObjects(filter,
                             LDAPGroup.getObjectClasses(),
                             env.getProperty("ldap.root.group"));

getGroups(): 804 ArrayList results = Collections.list(answer);
```

**searchObjects(...)**

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer;
      if(filter != null){
        answer = this.getDirctx().search(searchroot, filterstring, getSearchControls(filter.getLevel()));
      }
      else{
        answer = this.getDirctx().search(searchroot, filterstring, getSearchControls(-1));
      }

return answer;
```

**Java Doc from javax.​naming.​directory.​DirContext.search(...)**

```
Returns:
an enumeration of SearchResult objects
Throws:
NamingException - if a naming exception is encountered
```

The answer can't be null. It isn't possible. Did vaadin changed any depency in the version 6.7.10 that use or implement a NamingEnumeration or something else that could be responsible for this?

environment:

- Lifeary 5.2.3
- LDAP
- Vaadin - 6.6.0 - no Error
- Vaadin - 6.6.8 - no Error
- Vaadin - 6.7.0 - no Error
- Vaadin - 6.7.5 - no Error
- Vaadin - 6.7.9 - no Error
- Vaadin - 6.7.10 - Error
- Vaadin - 6.8.3 - Error

Comment: The code or errors don't look Vaadin related at all...

Comment: That was my thought,too. But I only updated the Vaadin Version. Nothing more. Some vaadin depencies responsible for something like this?

Comment: Have you cleaned and recompiled everything after version update? And Vaadin doesn't need any dependencies (expect GWT for widgetset compilation / client-side development)

Comment: The widgetset is from the vaadin version I've deployed in the lib directory. (Vaadin.jar -> VAADIN/widgetset). Are widgetset and vaadin version different, I will get a log message from liferay.